# pushPage終了時のちらつきが気になる。

Tags: onsen-ui

Cordova & OnsenUI　で AngularJSベースに開発しています。

OnsenUIのpushPageメソッドにて画面遷移をした場合に、iOS端末(iPhone6,iOS8)にて、ちらつきが発生してしまいます。

対策として、プレフィックス付きで、
backface-visibility: hidden;
を設定してみましたがちらつきが抑えられていません。

また、cssアニメーションで動かされている場合、translateをtranslate3Dにする対策もあるようですが、onsenui.jsを覗いてみると、translate3Dを使ってtransformしているようです。

もし、その他にちらつき抑制の方法をご存知の方がいましたら、ご教授いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

追記で失礼します。

今回の実装では、pushPageを使った遷移でも、ons-toolbarでのons-back-buttonを用いた遷移でも、[遷移後]にちらつき現象が起こっています。
ただし、毎度発生するわけではなく、1/3くらいの確率で起こります。

引き続き、抑制の方法を探しますので、解決しましたら、こちらでもご報告させていただきます。
もし解決済みの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授願います。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

`<ons-page>`がネストしてはいませんか？デベロッパーツールでDOM構造を確認してみてください。私も同じ問題で長い間悩まされてきたのですが、`<ons-page>`がネストしていることを発見し、これを解消したところ、`pushPage()`および`popPage()`時のちらつきが無くなりました。